# How to efficiently upload data from R to SQL Database (Snowflake)?

Tags: python, sql, r, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to create a function to upload a potentially large dataf rame (1M + rows) from R to Snowflake as efficiently as possible. The codes below is my current approach, I'm breaking the data frame into chunks of 100 records and looping through iterations of 100 rows, plus the remainder, via dbSendUpdate. This generally takes very long for a large data frame, is there a more efficient method I can use instead?

```
upload_func <- function (dataframe) {
for (i in 0:(nrow(dataframe)/100 - (nrow(dataframe)/100)%%1)) {
  if (100*(i + 1) <= nrow(dataframe)) {

    b <- 100*i + 1
    e <- 100*(i + 1)

    values <- paste0(apply(dataframe[b:e,], 1, function(x) paste0("('", paste0(x, collapse = "', '"), "')")), collapse = ", ")

    dbSendUpdate(connection, paste0("INSERT INTO database_table
                                  VALUES ", values, ";"))
  }

  else {
    values <- paste0(apply(dataframe[(i*100 + 1):(i*100 + nrow(dataframe)%%100), ], 1, function(x) paste0("('", paste0(x, collapse = "', '"), "')")), collapse = ", ")

    dbSendUpdate(connection, paste0("INSERT INTO database_table 
                                  VALUES ", values, ";"))
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure about R but you shouldn't be using loops at all for inserts. Use native functions provided by Snowflake like `COPY INTO...`etc which will be more efficient rather If that does not work then another way would be bulk insert with single `insert` statement

Comment: I've noticed there's a limit on the number of records dbSendUpdate is able to send, thus the loops. Do you know if bulk insert is affected by the same?

Comment: What @mad_ is recommending with `COPY INTO` is the correct way to get data into Snowflake the fastest.  Have R drop the data to a file on blob storage and then use `COPY INTO` to get it into Snowflake.  Any sort of `INSERT` statement will not be as efficient, especially for larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

To get the best performance, don't insert directly from R. Write the dataframe to csv files in cloud storage, create an external stage that points to this location and then use `COPY INTO`. This will take advantage of parallel processing to ingest the data. To optimize the number of parallel operations for a load, it is recommended to produce data files roughly 100-250 MB compressed.